# In docker-compose, why one service could reach another, but not the other way around?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm writing an automated test that involves running several containers at once. The test submits some workload to the tested service, and expects a callback from it after a time.

To run the whole system, I use `docker compose run` with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  service:
    build: ...
    ports: ...

  tester:
    image: alpine
    depends_on:
      - service
    profiles:
      - testing
```

The problem is, I can see "service" from "tester", but not the other way around, so the callback from the service could not land to "tester":

```
$ docker compose -f .docker/docker-compose.yaml run --rm tester \
    nslookup service

Name:      service
Address 1: ...

$ docker compose -f .docker/docker-compose.yaml run --rm service \
    nslookup tester

** server can't find tester: NXDOMAIN
```

I tried specifying the same network for them, and giving them "links", but the result is the same.

It seems like a very basic issue, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `docker-compose run some-container`, it starts a temporary container based on that description plus the things it `depends_on:`.  So, when you `docker-compose run service ...`, it doesn't `depends_on:` anything, and Compose only starts the temporary container, which is why the `tester` container doesn't exist at that point.

If you need the whole stack up to make connections both ways between containers, you need to run `docker-compose up -d`.  You can still `docker-compose run` temporary containers on top of these.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and definite answer! In the end, I came with `compose up --exit-code-from=tester`, not sure if it is the best way, though.